# NHibernate by code - Save entity with unsaved(transient) child entity

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following entity:

```
public class Item
{
public virtual long ID { get; set; }
public virtual Version Version { get; set;}
More properties...
}
```

In the entity mapping I have:

```
ManyToOne(p => p.Version, m => 
{
m.Column("VERSION_ID");
}
```

The entity `Version` is also mapped by code and it's ID is an auto generated sequence.
When I save an `Item`, I create a new `Version`, assign it to the `Version` property and save it. I want to save the `Version` entity only after the `Item` is successfully saved. Now it throws a `TransientObjectException`when I do this. Is it possible to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot save an entity that references a transient object through a mapped property (Item->Version) unless when mapping the property you specify Cascade.Persist or Cascade.All.

Another thing is that since you should be running that code in a transaction the order of inserts should not matter. In case an exception is thrown (or anything else bad happens) after you save Version but before you save the Item, the transaction should be rolled back and nobody is going to see the new version.

The snippet below shows how you can begin/commit a transaction with nHibernate. Notice that the transaction will be rolled back if it does not get commited before it is disposed.

```
using(var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
using(var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
     // Do your thing here...

     transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: So Cascading means the child entity will be saved together with the parent, and will be rolled back in case of an error?

Comment: Cascade.Persit will save the referenced entity when the parent is saved (explicitly or when the session is flushed). It is your responsibility to do it in a transaction that can be rolled back in case of problems. I have updated the answer with a snippet showing how it can be done.

Comment: The entity is saved in separate from the running code so having access to the transaction is difficult. I think I'll have to handle with Cascade.All for this to work.